# Вывод русских букв в документе Excel сформированном на PHP

Tags: php, excel

Доброго всем времени суток господа

[Для формирования Excel документов на PHP](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/changesets?ProjectName=phpexcel)

```
// все что нужно находится сдесь trunk/Classes/
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$phpexcel = new PHPExcel();
$page = $phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$page->setCellValue("B2", "Hello");
$page->setTitle("Test");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpexcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

Работающая конструкция, но... не могу понять, как сделать, что бы можно было использовать русские буквы

```
// в место
$page->setCellValue("B2", "Hello");
// пишу
$page->setCellValue("B2", "Привет");
```

На выходе пустое место. Подскажите, что нужно сделать, что бы можно было выводиьт и русские буквы тоже?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кодировка файла (c кодом) должна быть UTF-8

Comment: Вау! Так оно и оказалось, правда сам пробовал искать решение в другом направлении

Answer (score 3):

Определить кодировку строки, например [тут](http://www.online-decoder.com/ru).

Использовать функцию:

```
iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str2);
```